# Bind can't resolve specific domains - no A record to their ns

Tags: bind, ns-record

I'm getting a problem resolving a domain when their ns servers don't have an A record.

I'm running  bind 9.3.2P2.

For example domain:10gb.co.il

when trying from Windows dns servers it seems to work fine.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the same DNS servers in both cases or does BIND uses the root servers (the default config) and Windows the servers provided by your ISP?

Answer (score 1):

If the NS server don't have an A record how can BIND find out their IP address in order to query them? It can't, so it can't resolve domains served by them.

On a side note I've run a test myself and I've noticed that I can resolve *10gb.co.il* using the DNS servers of my ISP, but I can't by running `dig +verbose 10gb.co.il` (this uses the root name servers). Your issue is  caused by an improperly configured domain. My guess would be that the DNS servers of my and your ISP have the address of *10gb.co.il* in their cache, while the current setup of the domain is incorrect.